# send NameID claim without encryption in ADFS 2.0

Tags: adfs

My Service Provider issues a SAML 2.0 AuthRequest with a NameIDPolicy tag like so:

```
<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" 
       Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"/>
```

This causes ADFS 2.0 to correctly issue a SAML Response containing an encrypted NameID token created by a rule similar to the one found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/ea5efcff-4221-4af1-b434-4be5245cb0fa/)

```
<NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">    
        MyeHAMeGLojBt7fcc2DQtntXXFka0kybkR42ZTitTUs=</NameID>
```

So far so good, however, my Service Provider doesn't seem to understand the encrypted NameID claim and is expecting it to be unencrypted while at the same time having the name-format as `transient`

As per [this document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2010/02/17/name-identifiers-in-saml-assertions.aspx), ADFS2.0  treats request for transient or persistent NameID formats as privacy scenarios (and hence the encryption)

So my question then would be:
Is there any way to have ADFS 2.0 generate the NameID claim with Format=transient and an unencrypted NameID like so:

```
<NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">Joe</NameID>
```

Answer (score 5):

We had a customer with an issue connecting to our web application. We wanted to disable encryption to help debug what we were receiving. These are the steps they used to disable encryption on their ADFS 2.0 server:

- Click Start
- Click Administrative Tools
- Click Windows PowerShell Modules
- Then, at the Windows PowerShell command prompt, type the following:

  ```
  set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust –TargetName “target” –EncryptClaims $False
  ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

The way I've solved this goes like this:

1. Create a rule that extracts the UPN from AD
2. Create a transform rule that transforms the Incoming claim type: `UPN` to the Outgoing claim type: `Name ID` and choose the `transient` nameid-format from the 'Outgoing Name ID Format' dropdown

This causes AD to send the NameID in the format required:
    `<NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">Joe</NameID>`

(I'll leave this question 'unanswered' for a while incase someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

1º **get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust –TargetName “target”-EncryptedNameIdRequired**
(This will tell you if ADFS encrypt the nameID claim)

if EncryptedNameIdRequired= false, try:

**set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust –TargetName “target”-EncryptedNameIdRequired $true**
(This will turn the value EncryptedNameIdRequired= true)

I tried on my lab, but switch the value doesnt make any impact. In my case formato is not Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"/>. I wonder if that affects the proof.